# How to execute a specific subroutine code in background and get the result from it?

Tags: perl

How to execute a specific subroutine code in background?

I'd like to fire several instances of the ping subroutine below in parallel. I know it has been asked before but I couldn't find my way in resolving this. The examples I found led me to using fork, however I want to execute in background the subroutine code only and I need someway to the get the subroutine result later on in the main code.

Thank you very much.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ipfile = "ips.txt";
open (my $fh, '<', $ipfile) or die "I couldn't open file  $ipfile\n";
chomp (my @ips = <$fh>);
close $fh;
my %pingResult;
foreach my $ip (@ips) {
    ping ($ip);
}

foreach my $ip (keys %pingResult) {
    print "ping result for $ip: $pingResult{$ip}\n";
}

sub ping {
    my $ip = $_[0];
    $pingResult{$ip} = `/sbin/ping -t 1 -c 1 $ip | grep packet`;
    chomp ($pingResult{$ip});
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [`Parallel::ForkManager`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Parallel-ForkManager/lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm)

Comment: Or use threads.

Comment: @Borodin With P::FM it's a bit awkward to get the results back to the main program.

Comment: @PerlDuck: Just `use use forks::shared` and `share %pingResult`

Comment: @Borodin I've heard about `use forks` but never tried it out. If it's really that simple then you are right.

Answer (score 3):

The [`Parallel::ForkManager`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager) module provides for data to be returned to the parent process from the children. It works by serialising and writing it to a temporary file

The second parameter of the `Parallel::ForkManager->new` call must be the path to a directory where these temporary files may be stored, and the second parameter to a child's `finish` call must be a *reference* to the scalar value that should be returned. That scalar value may be a simple string or number, or it can be a reference to a hash or data if a complex structure must be provided

To collect the return data, you must define a `run_on_finish` callback which collects information about the terminating child process

In this case my `ips.txt` file just contains the eight letters `A` through to `H`, and I have used this code

```
sleep rand 5 + 2;
my $ping = rand 10;
```

as a representation of the `ping` action. The returned value is the random number `$ping`. The *ident* of each child is an index into the `@ip_addresses` array, and both the child and the parent can use this value to identify which address the child has processed

You may well want to return non-zero exit status values (the first parameter of the `finish` call) so that the parent can tell whether the ping failed completely. It's available from the `$exit_code` parameter of the `run_on_finish` callback

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Parallel::ForkManager;
use Cwd 'cwd';

use constant IP_FILE => 'ips.txt';

my @ip_addresses;
{
    open my $fh, '<', IP_FILE or die $!;
    @ip_addresses = <$fh>;
    chomp @ip_addresses;
}

my %ping_results;

my $pfm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(10, cwd);

$pfm->run_on_finish( sub {
    my ($pid, $exit_code, $ident, $exit_signal, $dump, $data) = @_;

    $ping_results{$ip_addresses[$ident]} = $$data;
});

for my $ident ( 0 .. $#ip_addresses ) {
    my $pid = $pfm->start($ident);
    next if $pid;

    sleep rand 5 + 2;
    my $ping = rand 10;

    $pfm->finish(0, \$ping);
}

$pfm->wait_all_children;

use Data::Dump;
dd \%ping_results;
```

#### output

```
{
  A => 4.40219991930888,
  B => 2.82913053498731,
  C => 3.34837183912413,
  D => 3.39050637182908,
  E => 6.6558553334059,
  F => 6.72843905721919,
  G => 4.73434782211797,
  H => 3.30697605942504,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some people consider [threads](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) dangerous and ugly. But especially in conjunction with [Thread::Queue](http://perldoc.perl.org/Thread/Queue.html) I like their elegance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue;

use constant NUM_THREADS => 2;

my $workitems = Thread::Queue->new();
my %pingResult : shared;

sub main
{
    # create 2 worker threads
    threads->create( \&ping ) foreach ( 1 .. NUM_THREADS );

    # put the IPs into our working queue:
    my @ips = qw(127.0.0.1 stackoverflow.com localhost);
    $workitems->enqueue(@ips);
    $workitems->end();

    # wait for the threads to finish:
    $_->join() foreach ( threads->list() );

    print Data::Dumper::Dumper( \%pingResult );
}

sub ping
{
    while ( my $ip = $workitems->dequeue() ) {
        my $result = `/bin/ping -t 1 -c 1 $ip | grep packet`;
        chomp($result);

        lock(%pingResult);
        $pingResult{$ip} = $result;
    }
}

main();
```

With `T::Q::enqueue()` you place "items" in the queue, in this case IP addresses. In this example you do this from the main thread. After you're done with filling up the queue you call `T::Q::end()`.

The `T::Q::dequeue()` (called from the thread `ping`) blocks until an item can be read and removed from the queue. The `ping` function then calls `/[s]bin/ping` and puts the result into the global hash `%pingResult`. The variable is marked as `shared` which means it is shared between all threads. Because of that you need to protect it against concurrent access by means of the `lock` function. It blocks until no one else holds the lock. The lock automatically unlocks when it goes out of scope, that is: after every single iteration of the `while` loop. (There is no `unlock` function.)

The second ping-thread does exactly the same and it's kind of random which thread processes which IP address. They both pick IPs from the queue until `T::Q::dequeue()` returns some falsy value and they then exit.

The call `T::Q::end()` unblocks all calls to `T::Q::dequeue()` (no matter whether the queue is empty or not) and thus eventually ends the `while` loops in the threads.

Btw: although the `T::Q` is shared between all threads (including main), there's no need to mark it as shared or lock it because it has built-in thread-safety and does all that under the hood.

Instead of using a global shared variable for the results you could also create a second result queue and let the ping-threads put their results in there and let the main thread dequeue them one by one.

**Note:** When using threads it's far better to **not** create a new thread for every single workitem (IP address) but to create N threads in advance and then feed them with work through a queue. Thread creation is expensive. The T::Q module is just perfect for this worker-thread model.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [IO::Pipe::Producer](http://search.cpan.org/~robleach/IO-Pipe-Producer-2.01/lib/IO/Pipe/Producer.pm).  It's designed precisely for this problem.  You would have to make an adjustment to your sub to print the result and the parent script can read it in through the returned handle.  You just call its getSubroutineProducer method in a loop and grab the handles for processing once the jobs all start:

```
use IO::Select;
use IO::Pipe::Producer;

my $obj = new IO::Pipe::Producer();
my $sel = new IO::Select;

my $pingHandle = {};
my $pingResult = {};

foreach my $ip (@ips) {
    my $handle = $obj->getSubroutineProducer(\&ping,$ip);
    $sel->add($handle);
    $pingHandle->{$handle} = $ip;
}
```

The above starts the ping jobs and then you use your IO::Select object to read from them in a non-blocking way, until there's no longer any output from any of the handles.  You might improve the following with a timeout, but I believe the ping command already has one...

```
while(my @fhs = $sel->can_read())
  {
    foreach my $fh (@fhs)
      {
        my $line = <$fh>;
        unless(defined($line))
          {
            $sel->remove($fh);
            close($fh);
            next;
          }
        $pingResult->{$pingHandle->{$fh}} .= $line;
      }
  }
```

Note, I used a handle to IP lookup to be able to put the output from the handle in the correct position in the pingResult hash.  Then all you have to do is print the results below.  Note, I removed the "\n" because I edited your ping sub to print the result and the "\n" there prevents potential buffering issues.  You might with to set $| to a non-zero value at the top of the script to force the buffer to flush every time.

```
foreach my $ip (keys %$pingResult) {
    print "ping result for $ip: $pingResult->{$ip}";
}


sub ping {
    my $ip = $_[0];
    $mypingresult = `/sbin/ping -t 1 -c 1 $ip | grep packet`;
    print($mypingresult);
}
```

Comment: Disclosure:  I wrote IO::Pipe::Producer.  So I guess this is somewhat of a shameless plug.  But I use it for all sorts of stuff like this.  The other answers are good too.  This is just another way to do it.

Comment: In fact, it would probably be better to use the getSystemProducer method in the same class since you're only executing a system call in the subroutine you're passing anyway.  Just take out the ping sub and call the method like this: `my $handle = $obj->getSystemProducer("/sbin/ping -t 1 -c 1 $ip | grep packet");` instead of calling getSubroutineProducer.